# SQL Query for printing a cross-referenced table on a website

Tags: php, mysql, sql, html-table

I'm having trouble printing out an attendance table in an efficient way. There is probably a term for doing this, but I have no idea what it would be so I'm having trouble searching for a solution. Pivot table is close, but not enough.

I have a MySQL database laid out like this (simplified):

```
Log_events(event_id, event_name, ...)
Log_members(member_id, member_name, ...)
Log_attendance(member_id, event_id, ...)
```

Log_events has all the data for the event, Log_members have all the data for each member and Log_attendance has an double id entry for each time a member has attended an event.

I'm trying to print out a table (HTML table with PHP) which has all the event as colums, and then all the members as rows. Then, using the log_attendance table I would print a tick or some info in each table cell where the member has attended an event, kind of like this:

```
Name    | Event1 | Event2 | Event3
----------------------------------
Member1 | X      | X      | X
Member2 |        | X      | 
Member3 | X      |        | X
```

I am having trouble figuring out how to do this without a ridiculous amount of nested queries. How would I do this efficiently?

Here's an example of the kind thing I'm trying to print out:
http://www.worldoflogs.com/guilds/30890/character/

Comment: possible duplicate of [get 2 columns in my query result](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13344169/get-2-columns-in-my-query-result)

Comment: Do you have any constraints on the number of events that can be displayed?

Comment: well my plan is to show all the evens for a month, around 16 events per display

Comment: I ended up using GROUP_CONCAT, I will post the answer here later when the required 8 hours has passed.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to do this is do a query for every different event and retrieve the members that attended to it:

```
$result=$mysqli->query("SELECT event_id, event_name from Log_events");
while($row=$result->fetch_array()){
     $query="SELECT member_name FROM Log_attendance 
              JOIN Log_members ON Log_members.member_id=Log_attendance.member_id
              WHERE Log_attendance.event_id='$row[0]'
     ";
     $res2=$mysqli->query($query);
     while($member_row=$res2->fetch_array()){
           //Do something with the info. Like store it so you can format the table later.
     }
}
```

Depending on the table you want to print you can do it the other way arround:

get a list of members, then retrieve the events they attended.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to make it work. From the link Clockwork-Muse posted, I found the MySQL function GROUP_CONCAT.

My query looks similar to this now:

```
SELECT a.member_id, p.member_name, c.* 

FROM Log_attendance a NATURAL JOIN Log_events r NATURAL JOIN Log_players p 

LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT a2.member_id pid, GROUP_CONCAT(a2.event_id) all_events 
        FROM Log_attendance a2
    ) c ON c.pid=a.member_id 

GROUP BY a.member_id
```

(If there's errors it's because I had to edit it a bit by hand)

Basically it concatenates all event id's into a string like "1,2,3,5,9" for each member. In PHP I first retrieve all the events, print the colums and for each member I compare this list string to the column's id. I have othere WHERE statements there to restrict the sizes of the results so it doesn't get too slow.